# dynamic addition to a list within Jquery && Asp.net application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, .net

I have an asp.net application in which i have this code :

```
<div class="divpere" >
                                        <div class="divfille1" ><label> Métier</label></div>
                                        <div class="divfille2" >
                                          <input type="text" name="nom" id="Text1"  value="" runat="server" />
                                          <asp:Button ID="addjob" Text="Ajouter" runat ="server"/>
                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                         <br /> <br />

                                    <h4>Mes métiers</h4>
                                    <br />

                      <div class="widgetcontent bordered">
                            <div class="row-fluid">
                               <div class="span3 profile-left">
                                <ul class="taglist" id="mess" runat="server">
                                    <li><a href="">HTML5 <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">CSS <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">PHP <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">jQuery <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Java <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">GWT <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">CodeNgniter <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">Bootstrap <span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>
                                 </ul>
                      </div></div></div>
```

and this script :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('.taglist a').click(function () {
                return false;
            });
            jQuery('.taglist a span').click(function () {
                jQuery(this).parent().remove();
                return false;
            });
            jQuery('#addjob').click(function () {
              //
            });
        });
```

the result is :

[image: im]
I'd like to complete the script to add the click event into the bouton which add a new element `ul` to the list with a title as the input content

- How can i do that?
- What is the best way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With method `append()` you can add to your `ul` a new `li` element

try this:

```
jQuery('#addjob').click(function () {
    $('.taglist').append('<li><a href="">' + $('#Text1').val() + '<span class="icon-remove"></span></a></li>');
});
```

When you add a dynamic element after if you want to fire it you need to change your previous code to this for example:

```
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.taglist a', function () {
            return false;
        });
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.taglist a span', function () {
            jQuery(this).parent().remove();
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: it is good idea : i deleted the runat="server" to avoid the postback but i got aways undefined as new value!!!!!

Comment: if the value is undefined means that you don't select the right element. @Lamloumi

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? @Lamloumi

Comment: nice i deleted all the runat="server", and it works fine.thanks,